# QGIS CRS for small island based on transformation with large rotations and tm-projection

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system

I am trying to create a CRS for QGIS based on a GPSsurvey and the related transformation and rotation parameters. Within OSGEO I defined a transformation and projection as follows:

```
cct +proj=pipeline +step +proj=cart +ellps=WGS84 +step +proj=helmert +convention=coordinate_frame +x=194.245 +y=-154.53 +z=102.676 +rx=351.5046 +ry=-701.841 +rz=251.9889 +s=6.296557 +exact +step +proj=cart +inv +ellps=intl +step +proj=tmerc +units=m +lat_0=17.63621319 +lon_0=-63.23752013 +x_0=4714.87 +y_0=1967.19 +k_0=1.0
```

If I import this string in QGIS in an adapted CRS, I get the proper transformation with test coordinates (N: 17.61578594 ° E: -63.25156367°) result in the proper local coordinate x=3215.43 m and y= -287.55 m)

However if a try to safe this CRS, QGIS replies that prof4 definition is not valid.

How should I proceed?

Comment: Are you trying to **save** the CRS?

Comment: you have +proj defined multiple times

Comment: Vince, I want to use this CRS within QGiS, in the test it works but when I cick on "OK" i get the message that the string is not valid.

Comment: Yes I use +proj   3  times since I have a projection (tmerc) and a translation with relative large rotations. So as far as I understand I have to apply the helmert option including the +exact flag and this combination seems to require a pipeline option

Comment: What has “small island” in your title got to do with your question?  A title should be a summary of what’s in the body.

Comment: I notice you are working on Saba. Can you elaborate what you are trying to achieve? Using gps coordinates in wgs84 lat long doesn't give you the required location precision?

Comment: Hans, I would like to combine Kadaster coordinates and UTM coordinates into one GIS  environment. I have the transformation and projection parameters (Based on a geodetic gps survey in 2009)  to go from WGS84 to local kadaster grid. These parameters work perfectly in the TRIMBLE survey system. I can also apply this transfromation in OSGEO. The rotations  are to large to use the "towgs" statement. My objective is to have a valid and accurate CRS to be used in QGIS for Saba.